# Video background grid overlay issue

Tags: html, css, video

This is probably a really obvious mistake that i'm missing, but anyway:

I'm having an issue with using a video as a background for a website and overlaying it with a semi-transparent 4x4px png image as a grid. The grid just  overlaps the video, so the video should show through the repeated transparent image, but it just seems to disappear.

Any help with this is appreciated immensely (even though it's probably just a really simple error on my behalf)

Here's some screenshots of the problem:

**Grid overlay issue**
[image: Grid appearing, no video though]
The grid appears, but no video through it (video looks like screenshot below)
[image: Video that should be showing through the grid]

The grid is a repeated 4x4px png, the white 2x2px are transparent and the grey 2x2px are at 75% opacity.

Here is grid.png blown up (too small to attach):

[image: blown up grid.png]

**EDIT: grid.png attached**

[image: grid.png]

**HTML**

```
    <div id="container">

        <div class="grid"></div>

        <!-- BG-VIDEO -->

        <video autoplay loop muted>
            <source src="video/video.mov" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="content">
            <center>
                <div class="titlebox">
                    <h1>The Redtree Cafe</h1>
                </div>
            </center>
        </div>



    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* VIDEO */

#container {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}


.grid {
    background: url(img/grid.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 1000;
}

/*Front Page*/

.titlebox {
    z-index: 2000;
}
```

Comment: If grid.png is hqR7r.png (posted) and is suppose to be semi transparent; it is not transparent it is opaque; It is non-transparent white and non-transparent gray.

Comment: No - hqR7r.png is a screenshot of grid.png, I couldn't attach the actual file

Comment: @Wayne - I've added grid.png to the post (it's very small though - your gonna have to squint)  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your video is rendering below the grid. One of the way to fix this is to add `position: absolute` to the grid element:

```
.grid {
    position: absolute;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/6wotw7u3/

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, could you please explain why the position needs to be absolute?

Comment: Because in that case you're able to layer elements one of top of another, they are not "pushing" the next element downwards, but are staying on top (or below) of it. That is just one of the possible solutions, you can try relative positioning combined with negative margins, fixed position, etc, but I think this is also the easiest. See this: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 0):

you can do this first  set

```
.grid{ opacity.1;}
```

it will make your grid transparent

if problem is still unsolved them is think problem is that you haven't given css to video

```
video { width:100%; height:400px;}
```

Comment: first remove your grid and see if video is there or not and let me know

Comment: Yes, video is there (with the original code as well as your code) if I comment out `<div class="grid"></div>`